# When using system() in c++ my program gets stuck, how do I get it to proceed?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I am making a disk utility tool that takes the diskstats (in linux) and calculates values from it. My basic problem is that when the system() call occurs, the program hangs there.

```
   system("grep 'sda ' /proc/diskstats | tee \"report.txt\"");
   ifstream inStream;
   inStream.open("report.txt");
if (inStream.fail()) {
    cout << "Report gathering failed." << endl;
    return;
}
while (!inStream.eof()) {
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream >> numReads1;
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream >> sectorReads1;
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream >> numWrites1;
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream >> sectorWrites1;
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream.ignore();
    inStream.ignore();
}
```

Comment: A `ptrace` on your program might turn up interesting data.

Comment: I'd start by using `popen` instead of `system`.

Comment: Are you able to run the command in a bash shell, independent of your program? Does it finish normally?

Comment: There are much better C++ ways of doing this than using `system` and intermediate files: [PStreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/), [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/), [POCO Process](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) - most of which are wrappers around `popen`.

Comment: Do you really mean to use `tee`? Try replacing the pipe to tee with output rediretion `>`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin can you give me an example of popen syntax?

Comment: `system("grep 'sda ' /proc/diskstats | tee \"report.txt\"")` is a prototypical example of cargo cult programming.

Comment: what's the type of numReads1,sectorReads1,numWrites1,and sectorWrites1? int or string or something else?

Comment: Actually, looking at how simple a pattern you're looking for with `grep`, it's probably easier to just open `/proc/diskstats/` and read it directly in your program. Oh, and don't use `while (!x.eof())` either--it's pretty much guaranteed to fail at detecting the end of input correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> `system("grep 'sda ' /proc/diskstats | tee \"report.txt\"");`

Why did you do this? Of course it's going to hang. `tee` copies all input to standard output and to each file specified as an argument to `tee`. You don't have anything reading from `tee`'s standard output. If there are enough matches, the output buffer will fill and the process will hang.

What you could have done using `system` is

```
system("grep 'sda ' /proc/diskstats > report.txt");
```

You don't need quotes around `report.txt`, and you don't need `tee`. However, there's no reason to write that file if you don't need it. You could have used `popen` instead:

```
FILE* grep_sda = popen (""grep 'sda ' /proc/diskstats", "r");
```

Note that the result of `popen` is a `FILE` pointer. You have three choices here:

- Use C-style I/O to read from that `FILE` pointer.
- If you are lucky, some systems offer non-standard constructors for `std::fstream` that construct a C++ file stream from a C stream.
- There might be a boost solution. I can't use Boost at work, don't use it outside of work.

Another option is to bypass the use of `grep`. There's no need for `grep` here since the pattern is so simple. Open the file as a C++ `std::ifstream`, read lines from it using `std::getline`, filter lines that match with `std::find`, and then parse the lines that do match.